# terminal starting zsh as subshell?

Tags: unix, terminal, zsh

I was wondering why my terminal is starting my default shell, `zsh`,  as a subshell, and how I can't change my SHLVL back to 0?

[image]

[image]

Comment: why do you think you're running in a subshell?  what does e.g. `pstree` show?  also fwiw my `$SHLVL` seems to start from 2 in every gui term i have.

Comment: If there is a `-` before your current shell, in this case `zsh`, then that means you are running a subshell.

Comment: huh, is that a BSDism?  my `ps` doesn't do that.  anyway the question still stands: what's the parent process?

Comment: It says `Login -pf <username>` is the Parent process.

Comment: @BrandonMercer If there is `-` before you current shell this means it is started as a login shell, nothing more. You can e.g. run `- zsh` in zsh and `$0` will be `-zsh`. In particular it does *not* mean zsh is *not* a subshell.

Comment: One example: by subshell `$()`/`\`\``/`()` is usually meant. `- zsh -f -c 'echo $0; (echo $0); echo $(echo $0)'` produces three `-zsh` strings.

Comment: * Sorry, did not mention you said that `-zsh` means that it *is* a subshell. It is not true either though. Basically you can run any process with any name on *nix, but `-*sh` is a common convention for naming login shells that has nothing to do with these shells (not) being subshells.

Comment: [Relevant](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch03_19.htm) [Links](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch03_04.htm).

Comment: @ZyX Forgive me, as I'm just picking up unix.  I'm reading a the book "From Bash to Zsh", and it states that if there is a `-` before the shell name, then it means that you are running a subshell.  That's where I was getting confused.

Comment: @BrandonMercer Failed to find this book. I have found “From Bash
to Z Shell: Conquering the Command Line”, but it does not state such a thing. At least, not in “Starting the Shell” chapter.